# Loadbalancing fails when a server is down

Tags: spring, load-balancing, netflix-zuul, netflix-ribbon

I have written a simple set of micro-services with the following architecture: [image]

For all, I have added `spring-boot-starter-actuator` in order to add `/health` endpoint.

In Zuul/Ribbon configuration I have added :

```
zuul:
  ignoredServices: "*"
  routes:
    home-service:
      path: /service/**
      serviceId: home-service
      retryable: true

home-service:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: localhost:8080,localhost:8081
    eureka.enabled: false
    ServerListRefreshInterval: 1
```

So that, each time client will call `GET http://localhost:7070/service/home`, loadbalancer will choose one of two HomeService which runs on 8080 or 8081 port and will call its endpoint `/home`.

But, when one of HomeService is shutdown, the loadbalancer does not seem to be aware (in spite of `ServerListRefreshInterval` configuration) and will fail with `error=500` if it tries to call the shutdown instance.

How could I fix it?

Comment: I have posted the same question (as issue) in spring-cloud-netflix github repository : https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1984

Comment: You have static hosts so I doubt that will work. AFAIK that will only work if you use service discovery but as your routes are static it will operate on the same 2 instances always (regardless of status of the services). Zuul is for proxying not for service discovery.

Comment: Agree. The goal was not to use zuul as a discovery service but to use ribbon for loadbalancing in the same gateway than zuul. An that, without using any discovery service (like consul or eureka)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received and tested a solution from [spring-cloud team](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1984).

Solution is [here in github](https://github.com/oterrien/micro-service-zuul-ribbon-hystrix)

To summarize:

- I have added `org.springframework.retry.spring-retry` to my zuul classpath
- I have added `@EnableRetry` to my zuul application
- I have put the following properties in my zuul configuration

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:7070}

spring:
  application:
    name: gateway

endpoints:
  health:
    enabled: true
    sensitive: true
  restart:
    enabled: true
  shutdown:
    enabled: true

zuul:
  ignoredServices: "*"
  routes:
    home-service:
      path: /service/**
      serviceId: home-service
      retryable: true
  retryable: true

home-service:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: localhost:8080,localhost:8081
    eureka.enabled: false
    ServerListRefreshInterval: 100
    retryableStatusCodes: 500
    MaxAutoRetries: 2
    MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 1
    OkToRetryOnAllOperations: true
    ReadTimeout: 10000
    ConnectTimeout: 10000
    EnablePrimeConnections: true

ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: false

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 30000
```

Answer (score 0):

Debugging timeouts may be tricky, considering there are 3 levels of routing alone (Zuul→Hystrix→Ribbon), not including async execution layers and the retry engine. The following scheme is valid for Spring Cloud releases Camden.SR6 and newer (I've checked this on Dalston.SR1):

Zuul routes the request through `RibbonRoutingFilter`, which creates a Ribbon command with the request context. Ribbon command then creates a LoadBalancer command, which uses spring-retry for command execution, choosing retry policy for the `RetryTemplate` according to Zuul settings. `@EnableRetry` does nothing in this case, because this annotation enables wrapping methods with `@Retryable` annotation in retrying proxies.

This means, your command duration is limited to the lesser value of these two (see [this post](http://ryanjbaxter.com/cloud/spring%20cloud/spring/2017/03/15/retrying-http-requests-in-spring-cloud-netflix.html)):

- [`HystrixTimeout`], which is a timeout for invoked Hystrix command
- [`RibbonTimeout * MaxAutoRetries * MaxAutoRetriesNextServer`] (retries kick in only if Zuul has them enabled in its configuration), where [`RibbonTimeout = ConnectTimeout + ReadTimeout`] on the http client.

For debugging, it's convenient to create a breakpoint in `RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient#executeWithRetry` or `RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient#execute` method. At this point, you have:

- `ContextAwareRequest` instance (e.g. `RibbonApacheHttpRequest` or `OkHttpRibbonRequest`) with request context, which containes Zuul's `retryable` property;
- `LoadBalancedRetryPolicy` intsance with load balancer context, which contains Ribbon's `maxAutoRetries`, `maxAutoRetriesNextServer` and `okToRetryOnAllOperations` properties;
- `RetryCallback` instance with a requestConfig, which contains HttpClient's `connectTimeout` and `socketTimeout` properties;
- `RetryTemplate` instance with chosen retry policy.

If the breakpoint is not hit, it means that `org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient` bean was not instantiated. This happenes when the spring-retry library is not in the classpath.